# Проблема с выводом изображений

Tags: изображения, php, yii

Для поиска изображений в папке и вывода их используется следующий код:

Код: Выделить всё

```
$year = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('yyyy', $model->date_post);
  $month = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('MM', $model->date_post);
  $day = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd', $model->date_post);
  echo $year;
  echo $month;
  echo $day;
  $path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../upload/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'/';
  foreach (glob($path.$model->photos."*", GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename)
  { 
    echo ('<IMG src=".$filename."">');
  }
```

Изображение успешно ищутся в папке файловой системы, но не выводятся в браузере, т.к.
в `$filename` получается путь `"W:\domains\localhost\protected/../upload/2013/10/07/5251d1f272bb6_2LJUq3Bf.jpg"`, а изображение открывается по пути:
`"http://localhost/upload/2013/10/07/5251d1f272bb6_2LJUq3Bf.jpg"`

в голову сразу приходит мысль резать строку до `/upload/`.., но хотел бы у вас спросить нет ли более элегантного решения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть:

```
$path = Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true).'/../upload/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'/';
```

Вроде так. Если что погугли "yii baseurl"

UPDATE:

```
$path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../upload/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'/';
$root_url = Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true).'/../upload/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'/';  
foreach (glob($path.$model->photos."*", GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename)
{ 
    echo ("<IMG src=\"".$root_url.basename($filename)."\">");
}
```

Comment: Теперь изображения не ищутся...

Comment: Всмысле? Ааааю $path - это у тебя папка? А потом в ней ты ищешь файлы и пытаешься вывести?

Comment: $path это путь до папки с изображениями, в котором, осуществ. поиск

Comment: @LANSELOT, обновил ответ.

Comment: Немножко подправил ваш ответ...
$path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../upload/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'/';
$root_url = Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true).'/upload/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day.'/';
и все заработало! Спасибо вам огромное)

Comment: @LANSELOT, ну да. Копировал и не заметил)